# Interactive web application with Django/Flask issue

Tags: python

I want to build a website that shows some data from a CSV file and collects some user data (which should be provided through some textbox widgets) and saves it in a CSV file(the same file). I already have a working Python code for the CSV handling.

The problem is that I'm not sure what programming languages I need to use besides Python in order to achieve that using Flask or Django. And I'm not familiar with web development.

Can I make it using only Python and Django/Flask(or any other web framework)? If not, what languages and resources do I need? And do I need a database for that? I tried some tutorials for both frameworks but Flask seems to need HTML and CSS, and Django wasn't much clear to me. Thank you.

Comment: "Flask seems to need HTML and CSS" - and how do you expect to make a website without them?

Comment: Flask and Django are web frameworks. They have the same goal but with distinct philosophy. Django is very opinionated while Flask is not. If you are starting I would suggest Flask, it is simpler

Comment: maybe with [Dash](https://plot.ly/products/dash/) you could build interactive page in Python. Maybe it doesn't need to work directly with HTML but it has function which names are based on HTML tags - ie. `html.Div()`

Comment: I see. Thank you all for the comments!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend going with Flask rather than Django, as you'll have far less to set up and far less to learn to get your project running.

You will need to learn HTML, and Jinja2 (flasks templating language) but this shouldn't be too hard.
Focus on how to do tables in HTML, and then learn about for loops in Jinja2.

You won't need to learn CSS unless you want to make it look pretty.

Comment: What about JavaScript? Is it needed for Flask development in my specific case? And what about the database? Do I need it to achieve what I want to do? Thank you.

Comment: It doesn’t look like you need a database or JavaScript from your original question.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with Flask and use Flask-Admin (https://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for basic CRUD.

Suggestions:

1. Move data from csv to sql database, you can start with sqlite.
2. Use Flask-Admin/Flask-Sqlalchemy, with 5-10 lines of code you will be able to get the application up and running.

Comment: Do I really need a sql database? For my specific case, I am not dealing with large amounts of data. The CSV files already contain some values, and the website is supposed to change it, but not add more data to it. So can't I use only Python and Flask to do it? Sorry for not making my original question clear enough.

Comment: It is cleaner to do with the database since you want to capture inputs and persist. SQLLITE is not a client-server database; it is a compact embedded database.